# Stopping redirect after AJAX request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to get a simple form to submit via AJAX to the submit.php page where it is sent to a database. When I submit it, it redirects to submit.php. I want it to submit without redirecting. Thanks in advance!

JS

```
var request;
$("#myForm").submit(function(event){
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    var $form = $(this);
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/submit.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData

        //Could something like this work? 
        //complete: function() {***Stop redirect?***}



    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.error(
            "The following error occured: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    request.always(function () {
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Add return false to the end

Comment: @Zarazthuztra Add return false where?

Comment: Let's say the line after event.preventDefault()

Comment: You don't need `return false;`. The `event.preventDefault()` that you already have should be enough to prevent the standard form submit behaviour (including the redirect). The fact that it doesn't implies there's some other problem here. Do you get any errors in the browser's console? Are you sure your function is being called? (Is that code in a document ready handler or in a script block after the form in question?)

Comment: @nnnnnn That's what I would think too. When I first saw the question that was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: No errors in my console

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called at all? Does your "Hooray it worked!" appear in the console? Add a `console.log("In the function");` as the first line (before `if (request) {`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the document ready when your code runs? If not, `$("#myForm")` is returning an empty jQuery object, therefore any handlers attached to it won't ever be called. Test this by saving the jQuery object to a variable and logging it to the console.

Two solutions:

- Move your code into a document ready handler: `$(function () { /* my code dependent on DOM elements */ });`
- Use an event listener instead of binding to elements: `$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function (event) { /* handler */ }`

There's nothing wrong with the `event.preventDefault();` line - it can stay where it is, although I prefer to place it at the very top unless it's part of a conditional - and `return false;` isn't needed.

*Reason I can answer this*: I just setup a local test for this and came across the same problem: my submit handler wasn't running at all. But then I realised my `<script>` tag was before the `#myForm` element but my code wasn't waiting until `#myForm` was in the document before trying to find it with `$()`.

*Edit*: Placing the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the `<body>` negates the need to wait for document ready in your case. It also speeds up page rendering, but that's a whole other discussion.

Comment: Have you done what nnnnnn said? Add a console log to the first line of the submit handler to see if it's running at all. If it's not: that's your problem.

Comment: I just did and it's not logging anything.

Comment: So your submit handler isn't being called. Check `$("#myForm")` contains the element you mean it to. That's the first port of call. Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Jquery 2.0.3 (latest)

Comment: The post request is being sent to submit.php because the inputs are showing up in the database.

Comment: If you turn Javascript off, that should still happen with `action="/submit.php"` in your `<form>` element. Try removing the `action` attribute whilst testing.

Answer (score 0):

Put the event.preventDefault(); right after the first code line the one with the .submit listener

Comment: It still redirects when I put 'event.preventDefault();' after '$("myForm").submit(function(event){'

Comment: It doesn't matter where in the function you put it (unless there is some error in the function that stops execution before it gets to the `preventDefault()`, but the solution to that is to find the error and fix it, not to move the `preventDefault()`).